# Как привести <QuerySet ....> в читабельный вид

Tags: python, django, tuple

У меня есть функция которая отдает такие данные.

```
<QuerySet [('edit_user',), ('add_user',), ('delete_user',), ('create_user',)]>
```

Как мне добиться вида типа `edit_user, add_user, delete_user, create_user.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryset.values_list(<field_name>, flat=True)` - преобразует кверисет в список.

В данном примере - `Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=user).values_list('choices_perm', flat=True)` создаст список - `['edit_user', 'add_user', 'delete_user', 'create_user']`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Для превращения списка в строку:

`", ".join(Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=user).values_list('choices_perm', flat=True))`

Получится

`edit_user, add_user, delete_user, create_user`

Comment: Дело в том что он уже приходит после этого.
user_perm = Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=user).values_list('choices_perm')

Comment: `Perm.objects.filter(user_perm=user).values_list('choices_perm', flat=True)`

Comment: А как теперь убрать квадратные скобки ? ['edit_user', 'add_user', 'delete_user', 'create_user']

Comment: вы хотите просто в строку одну всё это превратить?

Comment: Желательно конечно да

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: Ты просто ЛУЧШИЙ! Спасибо

Comment: Поотвечай еще на мои вопросы))